# Using memcached on XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, memcached

I am using XAMPP. When trying to use

```
$memcached = new Memcached();
```

I get the error: Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dir\index.php

I have done a lot of searching and cannot find a way to install Memcached.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have installed Memcached extension on your XAMPP PHP Version: If you working on UNIX enviroment you can simply install memcached using command

```
 // Step 1.
 $ sudo apt-get install memcached
 // Step 2.
 $ sudo apt-get install php5-memcached
 // Step 3.
 $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you using Windows enviroment you should use Memcache extension instead Memcached. Detail installation on windows bellow:

```
 http://zurmo.org/wiki/installing-memcache-on-windows
```